# Как в Spring Security вручную авторизовать пользователя?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Мне нужно авторизовать пользователей, которые входят через социальные сети. Т.е. не через форму. Как это можно сделать в Spring Security?

Я использовал такой код

```
 Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(new CustomUserDetails(user, getAuthorities(user)), null, getAuthorities(user));
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

Пользователь вроде как авторизуется, роли прописываются, НО когда я извлекаю список авторизованных пользователей

```
 List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
```

пользователей авторизованных таким способом в нем не оказывается.

Существует ли способ авторизации работающий корректно?

Comment: наверное Вы имели ввиду http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/ (туториал https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/)

Answer (score 1):

Вам есть смысл использовать oAuth и переписывать ваш 
сабкласс от WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter вот пример https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ или на крайний случай вызовите у вашего
сабкласса от WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter метод

```
public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
```

вот так

```
@Autowired
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter ws;

public void func(){
     Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(new CustomUserDetails(user, getAuthorities(user)), null, getAuthorities(user));
     ws.authenticationManagerBean().authenticate(auth);
}
```